# Scrolling down a whole page in Zathura

Tags: zathura

I have a problem in Zathura, namely that, if I read something where the text only uses some of the page, and zoom in on the text, then, when I press `ctrl+f`, I do not get the corresponding section of the next page, but the top of it, so I have to readjust manually for every page.  Is there a way to fix this?  Or are there better customizable pdf readers?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> scrolls full screen down. To scroll full page down press <kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>PgDown</kbd>.